# Why can't i scale this simple stage in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d-games

I am using this stage that contains a dialog as a simple menu. It is working correctly, but when I try to make it bigger by increasing dialog size it just scales in a really bad way. What can i do?

```
public Menu()
{
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("rusty-robot/skin/rusty-robot-ui.json"));
    stage=new Stage();


    Dialog dialog=new Dialog("Choose the number of players",skin);
    Button button= new Button(skin);
    dialog.setSize(630, 450);
    dialog.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, Align.center);
    final SelectBox<String> selectBox=new SelectBox<String>(skin);
    selectBox.setItems("Two Players","Three Players","Four Players","Five Players","Six Players");
    Game.isMenu=true;
    //dialog.getContentTable().defaults().pad(10);
    dialog.getContentTable().add(selectBox);
    dialog.getButtonTable().add(button);
    stage.addActor(dialog);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

...button listeners..

```
public void draw()
{
    stage.act();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: Need more detail to understand what your problem is. Like how you expect it to scale vs. what's actually happening. And what means you are using to scale it.

Comment: We need scaling code. Expected result and current.